# Link Issues with using precompiled headers in static library (MSVC)

Tags: visual-c++

I am compiling a series of static libraries with precompiled header with MSVC2017 and CMake. So the generating is done manually:

Generating PCH:

```
/Yc /Fp"C:\FullPath\precomp.pch"
```

Using:

```
/Yu"C:\FullPath\src\pch.h" /FI"C:\FullPath\src\pch.h" /Fp"C:\FullPath\precomp.pch"
```

This all works fine. The libs compile and link fine (and a lot faster, so the precompiling works).

Now I want to use these libs in another project and get linker errors for the symbols used by the precompiled header. I can fix these errors by adding the precompiledHeader obj into the new project, but I dont like it. The projects which are depending on the libs should not be aware whether the libs were built with precompiled header or not. My Question: Is there a way to realize this with static libs that already links in all objects needed so that depending projects just link? I could imagine if it were shared libs it work out of the box. Is there a way to include the symbols of pch.cpp.obj into the using lib?

Comment: Precompile headers require that all compilation settings are identical, so typically you generate a PCH for each library and not try to share them across libraries.

Comment: Yes I know( they have exactly the same compiler settings). But I have the same problem if i just use one lib. The depending Project cannot link certain objects. To be specific I use it for some boost headers of which the symbols are not found.

Comment: This rings a very obscure bell, rung many years ago by a custom build system that got this wrong as well.  It is very important to provide the *full* path name of the pch file.  So not just /Fp "precomp.pch" but /Fp "c:\foo\bar\precomp.pch".  The IDE never gets this wrong.

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks for the input. I left it out for briefness. It contains the whole path. I edited the post

Comment: Hmya, another five minutes of my life I'll never get back.  Next, "Link against: pch.cpp.obj" makes very little sense, a static library does not get linked.  When you finally use it then you link the .lib file, never an .obj file.  The IDE never gets that wrong either.  Consider to work backwards from good IDE sample projects that link properly to a CMake script that generates them.